# asp.net MVC HTTPPost return View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting below error after redirecting to view after HTTPPost.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType3`1[System.Int64]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVCProject.Models.AddEmployee'.
```

Scenario:

View will load using an num (if passed). I have another method HttpPost, that giving an error on the return View. Please see code below.

```
        public ActionResult AddEmployee(int? num)
        {
            AddEmployee e = new AddEmployee();

            //Business logic

            return View(e);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddEmployee(AddEmployee model)
        {
            //Add Employee logic
            return View("AddEmployee", new { num = model.EmpNum });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a view and not actually redirecting.  Highly recommend Googling and following the POST Redirect GET pattern.  Example would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(AddEmployee model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Add Employee logic
       var newEmployeeNumber = 1223; // Gotten from your add employee logic
       return RedirectToAction("AddEmployee", new { num = newEmployeeNumber });
   }
   return View(model);
}
```